# libc6 is installed, but my raspberry-pi doesn't think so

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, debian-jessie

I tried to install libstdc++6, libffi6, and a lot of other packages, which require libc6 on my raspberry-pi, raspbian jessie 2017 04 10, offline (I do not want to go online for my own reasons).

I looked if libc6 was installed (`apt list`, and `apt show libc6`). It was.
I tried to install the packages (`sudo dpkg libstdc++6_4.9.2-10_armhf.deb`)
and he told me, libc6:armhf wasn't installed!

It's making me mad! Some suggestions for solutions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm sorry for the question.
I solved it in a way I never thought it would work:
I just installed it with the GUI.
It doesn't work on the console (I used `bash`) for some reasons.
(or I made a mistake on the console)
But with the GUI (Right click -> `Install package`) it worked.
I checked it with the console and the GUI (`Add / Remove packages`)
It worked.

I'm sorry for this question.